# Error in importing environment OpenAI Gym

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am trying to run an OpenAI Gym environment however I get the following error:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
```

ERROR

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ale_py/gym/environment.py:11: DeprecationWarning: Importing atari-py roms won't be supported in future releases of ale-py.
  import ale_py.roms as roms
A.L.E: Arcade Learning Environment (version +a54a328)
[Powered by Stella]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/OpenAI Gym Stuff/OpenAI_Exp.py", line 2, in <module>
    env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 200, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 105, in make
    env = spec.make(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 75, in make
    env = cls(**_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ale_py/gym/environment.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.seed()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ale_py/gym/environment.py", line 171, in seed
    raise error.Error(
gym.error.Error: Unable to find game "Breakout", did you import Breakout with ale-import-roms?
```

Comment: it may need to find on internet original `ROM` with game  `Breakout`

Comment: or it may need to install `gym[atari]` or `gym[all]` to have all elements.

Comment: is this FULL error message? Code works for me with gym 0.18.0 but after update to 0.20.0 I see message `DeprecationWarning: Automatic importing of atari-py roms won't be supported in future releases of ale-py.` - so it seems some functions are depecated in newer version and this can make problems. You can try to install older version using `pip install gym==0.18.0` and checking `print( gym.__version__ )`

Comment: `gym 0.20.0` works for me if I downgrade `ale_py` from `0.7.1` to `0.7`  - `pip install -U ale_py==0.7`. See also issue on GitHub [AttributeError: module 'ale_py.gym' has no attribute 'ALGymEnv' #2432](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2432)

Comment: you can see also some information in [Release Note for 0.21.0](https://github.com/openai/gym/releases/tag/v0.21.0) (which is still only on GitHub). `pip install gym[atari] no longer distributes Atari ROMs that the ALE (the Atari emulator used) needs to run the various games. The easiest way to install ROMs into the ALE has been to use AutoROM.` Link: [AutoROM](https://github.com/PettingZoo-Team/AutoROM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code works for me with `gym` `0.18.0` and `0.19.0` but not with `0.20.0`

You may downgrade it with

```
pip install --upgrade gym==0.19.0
```

BTW: it may also need to install `gym[atari]` or `gym[all]` to have all elements to work.

---

Base on information in [Release Note for 0.21.0](https://github.com/openai/gym/releases/tag/v0.21.0) (which is not ready on `pip` but you can install from GitHub) there was some change in `ALE` (`Arcade Learning Environment`) and it made all problem but it is fixed in `0.21.0`.

> -The old Atari entry point that was broken with the last release and the upgrade to ALE-Py is fixed

But new `gym[atari]` not installs ROMs and you will need to use module [AutoROM](https://github.com/PettingZoo-Team/AutoROM)

> -pip install gym[atari] no longer distributes Atari ROMs that the ALE (the Atari emulator used) needs to run the various games. The easiest way to install ROMs into the ALE has been to use AutoROM.

---

**EDIT:**

Version `0.21.0` from GitHub works for me after installing

(it may need program `git` for it)

```sh
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/openai/gym
pip install autorom

AutoRom    

pip install --upgrade gym[atari]
```

[AutoRom](https://github.com/PettingZoo-Team/AutoROM) runs program which asks if you have license for ROMs and install ROMs in `AutoROM/roms` but I didn't have to move ROMs to other place.

```
AutoROM will download the Atari 2600 ROMs.
They will be installed to:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms

Existing ROMs will be overwritten.

I own a license to these Atari 2600 ROMs.
I agree to not distribute these ROMs and wish to proceed: [Y/n]:

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/adventure.bin                                                                                                                           
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/air_raid.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/alien.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/amidar.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/assault.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/asterix.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/asteroids.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/atlantis.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/atlantis2.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/backgammon.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/bank_heist.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/basic_math.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/battle_zone.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/beam_rider.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/berzerk.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/blackjack.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/bowling.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/boxing.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/breakout.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/carnival.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/casino.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/centipede.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/chopper_command.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/combat.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/crazy_climber.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/crossbow.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/darkchambers.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/defender.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/demon_attack.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/donkey_kong.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/double_dunk.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/earthworld.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/elevator_action.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/enduro.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/entombed.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/et.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/fishing_derby.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/flag_capture.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/freeway.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/frogger.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/frostbite.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/galaxian.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/gopher.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/gravitar.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/hangman.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/haunted_house.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/hero.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/human_cannonball.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/ice_hockey.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/jamesbond.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/journey_escape.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/joust.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/kaboom.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/kangaroo.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/keystone_kapers.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/king_kong.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/klax.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/koolaid.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/krull.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/kung_fu_master.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/laser_gates.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/lost_luggage.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/mario_bros.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/maze_craze.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/miniature_golf.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/montezuma_revenge.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/mr_do.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/ms_pacman.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/name_this_game.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/othello.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/pacman.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/phoenix.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/pitfall.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/pitfall2.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/pong.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/pooyan.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/private_eye.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/qbert.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/riverraid.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/road_runner.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/robotank.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/seaquest.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/sir_lancelot.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/skiing.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/solaris.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/space_invaders.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/space_war.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/star_gunner.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/superman.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/surround.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/tennis.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/tetris.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/tic_tac_toe_3d.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/time_pilot.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/trondead.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/turmoil.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/tutankham.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/up_n_down.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/venture.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/video_checkers.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/video_chess.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/video_cube.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/video_pinball.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/warlords.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/wizard_of_wor.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/word_zapper.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/yars_revenge.bin
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/AutoROM/roms/zaxxon.bin
Done!
```

---

After installation this code works for me without error and without `DeprecationWarning`.

```
import gym
import ale_py

print('gym:', gym.__version__)
print('ale_py:', ale_py.__version__)

env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
```

and it gives

```
gym: 0.21.0
ale_py: 0.7.1

A.L.E: Arcade Learning Environment (version +b7b0c1a)
[Powered by Stella]
```

Comment: That's good. For my purpose I reverted to gym version 0.8.0 for it to work.

Answer (score 15):

```
pip install gym[atari,accept-rom-license]==0.21.0
```

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me via terminal:

```
pip install gym[atari]
pip install autorom[accept-rom-license]
```

After installing gym, it is 80 games. After installing gym[atari], it is 267 games. And you have to accept the specific licenses to activate additional games.

Comment: Regular gym only comes with 4 classic control problems right? What '80 games' are you referring to?

Comment: Definitely not 4 games

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved even with newer gym (in my case 0.24.0 on a windows environment). After downloading the ROM (via AutoROM) and installing the ROMs via ale-import-roms you need to set the environment variable ALE_PY_ROM_DIR to the directory of the bins.

In python (in my case Jupyter - the environment-variable has to be defined beforehand, of course) you need:

```
from ale_py import ALEInterface
ale = ALEInterface()
```

After this you can (using namespace ALE/) e.g.

```
from ale_py.roms import SpaceInvaders
ale.loadROM(SpaceInvaders)
env = gym.make('ALE/SpaceInvaders-v5')
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is using the new [Gymnasium](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium) fork in `2023` I have set up `Breakout` locally on my mac using the following steps:

1. Create a `requirements.txt` file with the following dependencies:

   ```
    gymnasium[atari, all]

    swig

    Box2D

    box2d-kengz

    pygame

    ale_py

    autorom
   ```
2. Create a python virtual env and install the dependencies by running:

   ```
    python3 -m venv .venv

    source .venv/bin/activate

    pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

3. Run the following to accept the license

   ```
    AutoROM --accept-license
   ```

If you encounter any timeout issues during this step check out this github [issue](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3170#issuecomment-1458139111) for some tips.

4. Run the following python code to launch the environment

   ```
    import gymnasium as gym
    import ale_py

    from gymnasium.utils import play

    print('gym:', gym.__version__)

    print('ale_py:', ale_py.__version__)

    env = gym.make("ALE/Breakout-v5", render_mode="rgb_array")

    play.play(env, zoom=3)
   ```
5. press `space` to start the game and `s` and `d` to control it.

Enjoy...!

Comment: I can't seem to edit this answer but a possible improvement would be to wrap the commands in backquotes so that `__version__` comes out with the underlines intact (rather than making the text bold).

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure whats gone wrong with the formatting but the commands do have backticks around them at the moment

Comment: ah managed to sort it out now, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with conda:

1. install gym version 0.19.0, by,

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge gym=0.19.0;
   ```
2. install atari_py by

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge atari_py;
   ```
3. download the [Roms](http://www.atarimania.com/rom_collection_archive_atari_2600_roms.html), and unpack the RAR.
4. open a terminal, active your environment, and input:

   ```
   python -m atari_py.import_roms \<path to folder\>,
   ```

   which will copy
   the ROMs in the folder specified to the pkg folder.