# How do I install the Atari environments from openai-gym?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mut_u40Sqz4&t=883s) at the 1:47:40 mark, he types in the following code:

```
!python -m atari_py.import_roms .\ROMS\ROMS
```

I have already downloaded the ROMS folder and the path for it is 'current_directory/ROMS/ROMS' so I believe the last part of this command is correct. However, when I run this command I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atari_py\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ale_python_interface import *
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atari_py\ale_python_interface.py", line 17, in <module>
    ale_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atari_py\ale_interface\ale_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Ultimately I would just like this code to work:

```
environment_name = 'Breakout-v0'
env = gym.make(environment_name)
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?
Thanks

Comment: similar problem was yesterday in other question. [Error in importing environment OpenAI Gym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442971/error-in-importing-environment-openai-gym/69443797#69442971)

Comment: normally I needed only `pip install gym[atari]` to install it. And it installed also ROMS. In newest `gym 0.21` it needs module `AutoROM` to install ROMS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in importing environment OpenAI Gym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442971/error-in-importing-environment-openai-gym)