# error in Gym eplus environment reset. Could not find platform dependent libraries and kernel always busy

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, energyplus

Could not find platform dependent libraries and kernel always busy. Im waiting and kernel still busy but my energyplus was completed succesfully.

```
[2024-03-08 14:58:19,486] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

[2024-03-08 14:58:19,486] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

[2024-03-08 14:58:19,575] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>

[2024-03-08 14:58:19,575] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>

[2024-03-08 14:58:19,580] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

[2024-03-08 14:58:19,580] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

[2024-03-08 14:58:47,259] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:EnergyPlus Completed Successfully.

[2024-03-08 14:58:47,259] EPLUS_ENV_TesisDivEnv_MainThread-EPLUSPROCESS_EPI_0 ERROR:EnergyPlus Completed Successfully.
```

I wanna finished this training of RL

Comment: A bit more context is needed: what versions of the libraries and Python you use?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what environment you use too, but commonly, the `ale-py` version could cause issues on `env.reset()` already. The Atari Breakout environment for example often has such problems. I recommend first:

-Downgrade to ale-py 0.7.4: `pip install ale-py==0.7.4`

If that changed something in the env.reset() output, that's already a good sign. You might further need to downgrade to `gym` version 0.25.2, and I saw some cases where a downgrade to 0.21.0 is needed (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69442971/19626271)).

If these still do not fix the problem, last tip I have is check if you need these libraries: `pyglet`, `baselines` etc.

Comment: that's still busy, i have been downgrade my gym to 0.22.0 versions. Im using BCVTB which notification error is same